# Get next button element with jquery

Tags: jquery

```
i have the following markup:

<form method="post" action="#">
<tr>
    <td><input class="" name="fees_word"  class="autoupdate" value=""/></td>
    <td><input class="" name="fees_figure" class="autoupdate"   value=""/></td>
    <td><button type="button" class="btn hide">Update</button></td>
</tr>
 <tr>
   <td><input class="" name="fees_word"  class="autoupdate" value=""/></td>
    <td><input class="" name="fees_figure" class="autoupdate"   value=""/></td>
    <td><button type="button" class="btn hide">Update</button></td>
</tr>
 </form>
```

onkeyup on any input, i want to change the class of the button in the same table row with it to show.

tried this:

```
<script>
$('input').keyup(function(){
  var val = $(this).val();
  $(this).next('button').removeClass('hide');
});
</script>
```

But no luck,how can i make this work.Thank you

Comment: `next` is used for sibling elements.

Answer (score 3):

You should first take corresponding table row with [`closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) and then within it [`find`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) a button:

```
$('input').keyup(function() {
  var val = $(this).val();
  $(this).closest('tr').find('.btn').removeClass('hide');
});
```

You can't use [`next`](http://api.jquery.com/next/) method because input fields and buttons are not sibling elements (they have different parents).